# JNI ReferenceTable overflow: how to release ObjectArray containing Strings

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I am having a frustrating time resolving this issue and the JNI documentation is woefully sparse. Assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Am assigned a project on an Android networking app. The native side stores information about the users you are connected to and I need to send this user list to the Java side to update UI info. Essentially I need to compose a string array and a boolean array which contain the names and flags of connected users, but later more info may be sent. My difficulty is in releasing & cleaning up the Object array containing the String information. I am not clear on how to do this. Here is what I have:

```
void name_list_cb(struct user_info* user_list, size_t count, void *userdata)
{
    jobject callbacks = (jobject)userdata;
    JNIEnv *env;
    (*g_vm)->GetEnv(g_vm, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, callbacks);
    jmethodID method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "user_list", "([Ljava/lang/String;[Z)V");

    int i;
    jobjectArray name_list;
    jbooleanArray connected_list;

    name_list = (jobjectArray)(*env)->NewObjectArray(env, count, (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String"), (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, ""));
    connected_list = (jbooleanArray)(*env)->NewBooleanArray(env, count);
    uint8_t boolean_arr[count];
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, name_list, i, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, user_list[i].name));
        boolean_arr[i] = user_list[i].connected;
    }
    (*env)->SetBooleanArrayRegion(env, connected_list, 0, count, (jboolean *)boolean_arr);

    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, callbacks, method, name_list, connected_list);
    (*env)->ReleaseBooleanArrayElements(env, connected_list, (jboolean *)boolean_arr, 0);

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, name_list, i), user_list[i].name);
        //(*env)->ReleaseObjectArrayElements(env, name_list, count, 0);
    }

    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, boolean_arr);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, name_list);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, connected_list);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cls);
}
```

I get either a "referencetable overflow", or a "signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad". The overflow/memleak is the main prob. Basically I am not releasing the UTFChars and the Object elements. Although I have seen references to it online, my JNI version does not have ReleaseObjectArrayElement[s]. I have been researching how to do this exactly but no luck so far!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, boolean_arr); because boolean_arr is C function stack variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef jarray          jobjectArray;   
void        (*DeleteLocalRef)(JNIEnv*, jobject);
```

So I think use DeleteLocalRef could release the jobjectArray.
Or you can just new the jobjectArray just one time in an initialize method.